# Using Moq, How can I change the Setup of a method in the Callback of another method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm trying to mock a third party component for my tests.
The component can store a byte array, but has no property, only two methods to access it.

```
// simple demo code, _comp is an object of this component
byte[] val = new byte[] { 5 };
// write new value
await _comp.WriteAsync(val);
// read value
byte[] newVal = _comp.ReadAsync();
```

Now in my tests, I thought I could just Setup the WriteAsync method to change the Setup of the ReadAsync method to return the passed in values.

```
Mock<IComponent> comp = new Mock<IComponent>;
comp.Setup(x => x.WriteAsync(It.IsAny<byte[]>())).Callback<byte[]>(bytes =>
        {
            comp.Setup(x => x.ReadAsync()).ReturnsAsync(bytes);
        });
```

But when I debug the demo code in my tests everything works well, the line with

```
comp.Setup(x => x.ReadAsync()).ReturnsAsync(bytes);
```

is called with the right values, but when the `WriteAsync` call returns I get a `NullReferenceException` in the demo code in the line

```
await _comp.WriteAsync(val);
```

I do not know what is null here, `_comp` and `val` are not.
I believe it is something deep within the Moq-framework, but I don't get any stacktrace info about that. Stacktrace only contains my demo code.

Am I doing something wrong here?
Or is it not possible to change a Mock-object from within one of its own callbacks?
I think, what I need could be done with a property, but unfortunately the component doesn't have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the written bytes in a local variable as a backing store for the mock. In the callback you set the value of the array so that it is available when used in the ReadAsync.

The `WriteAsync` is also an async method so it needs to return a `Task` to allow the async flow.

```
Mock<IComponent> comp = new Mock<IComponent>();
byte[] bytes = null;
comp.Setup(x => x.WriteAsync(It.IsAny<byte[]>()))
    .Callback<byte[]>(b => bytes = b)
    .Returns(Task.FromResult((object)null));
comp.Setup(x => x.ReadAsync()).ReturnsAsync(bytes);
```

Update based on comments.

In the comments it was mentioned that the WriteAsync return `Task<bool>`. While the condition of the return value is unknown based on what was provided in the OP, an example of have a condition based on the provided array can look like this

```
.Returns<byte[]>(b => Task.FromResult(b != null && b.Length > 0));
```

Comment: Thanks. This works well. 
But it also puts me to the reason, I', getting the exception. My Setup(...) was missing the Returns(...) call, because WriteAsync return Task<bool> so I think the Moq was raising the exception because of the null return.

Comment: What are the conditions for the returned Boolean? You can update the `Returns` action based on what is expected

Comment: Yes, thank you. My initial mistake was to ignore that WriteAsync is specified as Task<bool> WriteAsync(byte[] bytes) and I did not specify the Returns() value. What value is returned here is not relevant for my test case, but thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

So for others who stumble upon this, my initial code works, but when the method will return something other than void, one must specify this.
Async methods return Task or Task<>, so the Setup code should be e.g.

```
Mock<IComponent> comp = new Mock<IComponent>;
comp.Setup(x => x.WriteAsync(It.IsAny<byte[]>())).Callback<byte[]>(bytes =>
    {
        comp.Setup(x => x.ReadAsync()).ReturnsAsync(bytes);
    }).ReturnsAsync(true);
```